# How does this code iterate through the Integer value of the HashMap?

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I just completed a Sololearn course where I had to write a code to get the player with the highest score from a HashMap. However I dont understand how does this code know that Im interested in the values, not in the keys:

```
public void getWinner(){
    String nameArr[] = new String[players.size()];
    nameArr = players.keySet().toArray(nameArr);
     
    String bestplayer = nameArr[0];
    int maxValue = players.get(nameArr[0]);
    
    for(String player : nameArr){
        if(players.get(player) > maxValue){
            bestplayer = player;
            maxValue = players.get(player);
    }
    }
    System.out.println(bestplayer);
    }
```

As you can see, somehow the program automatically know that I want the Integer value of the player, not the String, which contains their name.

The HashMap contains their name as keys and their score as Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs for get(Object key)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped

For example in `int val = players.get(player)`:

- the HashMap is `players` (with mapping of `<String, Integer>`)
- the key is `player` of data type `String`
- the returned value is `val` of data type `Integer` which can be compared to `maxValue`

Comment: Maybe explicit the answer by explaining that the original hashmap is <String, Integer>

Comment: Ohh so the .get() method on Maps is programmed to get the value of the keys, and I go over the map with the use of an array and an enhanced loop. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see players is a HashMap<String, Integer> which means it has a key value pair with string key and integer value right? So to get the value from HashMap u need to call a get(key) function which is what this code is doing:

```
int maxValue = players.get(nameArr[0]);
```

Now how does he knows about the keys of HashMap is done via this code:

```
 String nameArr[] = new String[players.size()];
 nameArr = players.keySet().toArray(nameArr);
```

First it created a string array of same size of hashmap then it took out the key set and converted it into the array. And the for loop we see at the last portion is calculating the highest score of the player by looping through the key set array and taking out the values by HashMap.get(String key)